# Shouldn't only the last digits of a Dynamic IP change when we are assigned a new temp IP?

Tags: ip, internet

I kept track of my IP the past months and I noticed that for a few months I had for example an IP starting with 92.*. Then the next month I had a different one starting with 79.*. How is this possible? I thought only the last digits of an IP change when we have a dynamic one. I didn't move to another location/change provider. The geo-location remained the same though.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Security SE! I'm voting to move/close since the question is about networking and not security.

Answer (score 4):

ISPs have a pool of IP addresses, these blocks of IP addresses are assigned by IANA. It may be your ISP owns lets say 92.10.x.x.

This was good at some point but then then your ISP grew, of course IANA probably already sold the adjacent blocks, so they just assigned another free IP block.

So no it is not surprising all.

Comment: So basically the first digits of an IP address don't indicate geo-location at all, correct? I am confused because some told me if I have a Dynamic IP only the last 4 digits or so will change, the rest will remain the same.

Comment: Geolocation is added to IANAs index after they assign it. It is not predetermined

Comment: Ah now I understand. And why in some cases only the last 4 numbers or so change and the rest remain the same? Is it the same case again?

Comment: Its arbitrary, it also depends how your ISP was set up.

Comment: I see. One last question. Do Internet Cafes have one IP? For example do all computer users within that cafe have the same IP address or not at all? And I assume cafes also have Dynamic ones, right?

Comment: Note that IANA won't be allocating IP addresses directly to your ISP. Your ISP will receive the IP ranges from a RIR  (which itself received big chunks from IANA). Very old companies did receive allocation directly from IANA back in the day, though.

Comment: You might want to specify that this is called classful networking.